# Checking whether the two variable function is increasing or decreasing over a path

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

The function $f(x,y)=200+0.02x^2-0.0001y^3$ represent the depth of the river. A boat is moving from $(80, 60)$ to $(0, 0)$. The question is: is the river getting deeper or shallower when boat moving. We can take the straight line path joining the points and check the depth in that path. Is it possible? But I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't know much about multivariable calculus but you can consider the partial derivatives and check whether they are greater than or smaller than zero, you can check their increasing and decreasing interval.

Comment: I suppose since you know you are on the line $y=0.75 x$, you can substitute for $y$ and then take the derivative of the one-input function.